# The type 'StackedColumnSeries' does not support direct content

Tags: charts, uwp, winrt-xaml-toolkit, datavisualization.toolkit

I am trying to use WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization.UWP to show diagrams and charts, but i run into the following problem:

[image]

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: when I am using <charting:StackedColumnSeries.SeriesDefinitions>: it don't show anything just the titles

Comment: _just the titles_ is a start anyway, the posted snippet is just invalid. I don't see any control getting data anywhere (no ItemsSource). Post a minimal example, and post code as text, not as pictures.

Comment: As @HenkHolterman mentioned, can you please post a minimal example? Base on the [official sample](https://github.com/xyzzer/WinRTXamlToolkit/blob/54f94a78ef108e7273ee52816cd4f464c293fc9a/WinRTXamlToolkit.Sample/Views/Controls/ChartTestView.xaml) of this toolkit, there should be no problem with your code in your image.

Comment: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40609870/uwp-stackedlineseries-doesnt-show-values

this is the sample, but as I see there is no supported way to bind data in stacked series/charts

Comment: Don't repost, you can _edit_ a question.