# UWP StackedLineSeries doesn't show values

Tags: binding, uwp, winrt-xaml, data-visualization, datavisualization.toolkit

I am trying to use WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization.UWP

trying to draw any of the stacked charts like this:

[image]

But only this comes out:

[image]

Please help me, I have to use stacked series but the framework doesn't act as it should be..

Comment: Have you checked for binding errors in the Output tab within Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes and there is no binding error..

Comment: Have you tried to change the mode of the binding to OneWay? {Binding Records, Mode=OneWay}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I don't know how you define the code behind, I just provide the sample code as follows which can create a `StackedLineSeries` chart successfully.

XAML Code

```
<Page
x:Class="CStackLineChat.MainPage"
...
xmlns:charting="using:WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting" 
mc:Ignorable="d">
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Padding="50"  > 
    <charting:Chart x:Name="MyChart" Title="Stacked column Chart">
        <charting:StackedLineSeries>
            <charting:StackedLineSeries.SeriesDefinitions>
                <charting:SeriesDefinition                       
                    DependentValuePath="Amount"   
                    IndependentValuePath="Name"
                    IsTapEnabled="True"
                    Title="Doodad"    />
                <charting:SeriesDefinition
                    Title="Stan2"                      
                    DependentValuePath="Amount"
                    IndependentValuePath="Name"/>
            </charting:StackedLineSeries.SeriesDefinitions>
        </charting:StackedLineSeries> 
    </charting:Chart> 
</Grid>
</Page>
```

Code behind

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private Random _random = new Random();
    List<NameValueItem> Records = new List<NameValueItem>();
    List<NameValueItem> Records2 = new List<NameValueItem>();
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent(); 
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Records.Add(new NameValueItem { Name = "Name" + i, Amount = _random.Next(10, 100) });
            Records2.Add(new NameValueItem { Name = "Name" + i, Amount = _random.Next(10, 100) });
        }
        this.RunIfSelected(this.MyChart, () => ((StackedLineSeries)this.MyChart.Series[0]).SeriesDefinitions[0].ItemsSource = Records);
        this.RunIfSelected(this.MyChart, () => ((StackedLineSeries)this.MyChart.Series[0]).SeriesDefinitions[1].ItemsSource = Records2); 
    }
    private void RunIfSelected(UIElement element, Action action)
    {
        action.Invoke();
    } 
}

public class NameValueItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
}
```

And the result
[image]

Additionally, by testing on my side, it seems like `DependentValuePath` and `IndependentValuePath`  properties can not directly binding in your scenario. The best way to use this package is to follow the  [official sample](https://github.com/xyzzer/WinRTXamlToolkit/tree/master/WinRTXamlToolkit.Sample). [Here](https://github.com/xyzzer/WinRTXamlToolkit/blob/master/WinRTXamlToolkit.Sample/Views/Controls/ChartTestView.xaml) is the chart sample.

Comment: Thank you!
It's worked this way(with the code behind) but will use it in MVVM pattern, so bind it to a property which is in the ViewModel..
As I see in the chart sample the developer don't use binding in stacked charts, only in the simple ones...maybe because it is not supported still?
btw thanks for the help, I will check this sample deeply.

Comment: @Farkangyal actually I cannot tell whether it is supported through the official document is poor.  As testing on my side, binding is not work. please try to  do more testing about `DependentValueBinding`. For new issues you can open new thread for helping. Thanks.